# Passing callback twice in single function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, firebase

I have created a function to fetch values from firebase. Now the variables in which I stored result of the firebase query is only accessible inside firebase operation. However I require those variables outside the function so I created callback function to overcome this problem.

My code looks like this:
I have two firebase databases. 
One is to store registered users (ref1) and another one is to store paid users(paidRef). I need to check the one who has login is a registered user or a paid user.

```
var paidRef=new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/paidUsers");
var ref1=new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/tempUser");

function checkPaidUsers(res,callback){

 ref1.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(jsonData.userId).once('child_added', function(snap) {

 registeredUser=true;
  paidRef.on('child_added',function(snapshot) {
   if(snapshot.child('userId').val()==jsonData.userId )
   {

      paidFlag=true;
      return callback(registeredUser,paidFlag,res);
   }
   else
   {

      paidFlag=false;
      return callback(registeredUser,paidFlag,res);
   }

 })

})
}
checkPaidUsers( res,function(registeredUser,paidFlag) {

  if(registeredUser!=true)
  {
     newUser=true;


  }
return res.send({paidFlag:paidFlag,registeredUser:registeredUser,newUser:newUser});})
```

This code gives error as below:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

This error is coming because the callback function is called as many times as no. of children paidRef has because in case the user is not found in paidRef database it goes to else block and execute callback function.
Whats the best possible way to solve the problem of getting all the information of registered users as well as paid users from a single callback function.

Comment: If you're querying with `ref1.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(jsonData.userId)`, why don' you store the users under their userId: `/tempUsers/$uid`. Then you can easily get the user you're looking for for `ref1.child(jsonData.userId).once('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling the callback once for every user in paidRef, which doesn't seem to be your intention.
This code should only call the callback once.

```
var paidRef=new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/paidUsers");
var ref1=new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/tempUser");

function checkPaidUsers(res,callback){

 ref1.orderByChild('userId').equalTo(jsonData.userId).once('child_added', function(snap) {

 registeredUser=true;
  paidRef.child(jsonData.userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var paidFlag = false;
    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
      paidFlag = true;
    }
    callback(registeredUser, paidFlag, res)
  })
})
}
checkPaidUsers( res,function(registeredUser,paidFlag) {

  if(registeredUser!=true)
  {
     newUser=true;


  }
return res.send({paidFlag:paidFlag,registeredUser:registeredUser,newUser:newUser});})
```